# Displaying a div once its within the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 10 div elements, and all of them are 500px width and height;

```
<div class="cont_1">a lots of content here..</div>
<div class="cont_2">a lots of content here..</div>
<div class="cont_3">a lots of content here..</div>
<div class="cont_4">a lots of content here..</div>
<div class="cont_5">a lots of content here..</div>
<div class="cont_6">a lots of content here..</div>
<div class="cont_7">a lots of content here..</div>
<div class="cont_8">a lots of content here..</div>
<div class="cont_9">a lots of content here..</div>
<div class="cont_10">a lots of content here..</div>
```

and my css

```
div{
width:500px;
height:500px;
background:#f0f0f0;
border:1px solid #ccc;
margin:10px;
padding:10px;
}
```

And my seventh div is hidden with `display:none`. Once the user scrolls to this element how can I display it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to attach a scroll event to your page that checks the position of each element after scrolling:

```
function CheckIfVisible(elem){
var ElemPos = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
elem.style.display = (ElemPos > 0 && ElemPos < document.body.parentNode.offsetHeight)?"block":"none";
}

window.addEventListener("onscroll", function(){
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("cont_1")[0];
CheckIfVisible(elem);
});

window.addEventListener("onscroll", function(){
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("cont_2")[0];
CheckIfVisible(elem);
});

window.addEventListener("onscroll", function(){
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("cont_3")[0];
CheckIfVisible(elem);
});
```

and so on...