# display sticky div if within viewport

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am basing my code off of [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405916/displaying-a-div-once-its-within-the-viewport).

I have a parent div that is half way down the page. Within that parent div I want to display a sticky footer div, but only when viewport is showing the parent div. I have tried 4 different tutorials so far with no luck.

The page structure is this:

```text
HEADER
HERO
CONTENT RIGHT-SIDE(id="wrap-vs")
CONTENT-FULL-WIDTH
FOOTER
```

When RIGHT-SIDE is within view, I want to display a sticky div within it. You can't see RIGHT-SIDE when page loads, you need to scroll down to it. Also, when we are below it I want the sticky div to go away.

```js
var targetdiv = document.querySelector('.tabs');
console.log(targetdiv);
targetdiv.style.display = "none";

function CheckIfVisible(elem, targetdiv) {
  var ElemPos = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  targetdiv.style.display = (ElemPos > 0 && ElemPos < document.body.parentNode.offsetHeight) ? "block" : "none";
}

window.addEventListener("onscroll", function() {
  var elem = document.querySelector('#wrap-vs');
  CheckIfVisible(elem, targetdiv);
});
```

```css
#wrap-vs {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.tabs {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap-vs">
  <div class="tabs">
    right-side content sticky div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be worth investigating IntersectionObserver instead of having to check 'manually' each time the user scrolls.

Comment: Note that you'll also get more accurate answers if you can recreate a simple working example of the issue.

Comment: Hello, I am investigating IntersectionObserver right now, if I have no luck with it I will re-post with jsfiddle (it is looking promising though)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

```js
 

// Create a new observer
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries) {
    entries.forEach(function (entry) {
        // Log if the element and if it's in the viewport
    
        console.log(entry.isIntersecting);

        if(entry.isIntersecting == true){
            document.querySelector('.tabs').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.tabs').style.display = 'none';
        }
        

    });
});

// The element to observe
var app = document.querySelector('#wrap-vs');

// Attach it to the observer
observer.observe(app);
```

```css
#wrap-vs {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.tabs {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap-vs">
  <div class="tabs">
    right-side content sticky div
  </div>
</div>
```